# Fantasy Draft Tool

Tags: php, mysql, stateful

I'm attempting to mitigate some of the fantasy football draft issues I've had the last few years by creating my own drafting tool. The major requirement, similar to the major draft tools out there (ESPN, Yahoo, CBS Sports, NFL, etc) is to allow people to log in and participate in the draft. I'd like for the draft to be started by an Admin, and be running regardless of if anyone else logs in or logs out, it just needs to run; draft status, draft clock, next team to choose.

I'm familiar with PHP and MySQL however, I'm not thinking this will be enough as I can't maintain the state of the draft using PHP...at least I don't think so to handle this. What would be the recommended avenues to pursue to handle the above requirement?

Comment: If no one is logged in, does it really need to continue running? PHP is a general-purpose scripting language, I've seen people writing terminal-interactive programs with it before. Not that I recommend it. Ruby or Python or Perl would all be my choices before PHP, but you can do it with PHP, sure.

Comment: +1 to counter act the unexplained downvote.  While the title is rather weak, the question itself is decent.

Comment: The start of it will be triggered manually by the admin of the draft, who can also make selections for teams, so yes it would have to keep running. I thought about Ruby, so maybe nows the time to start learning it.

Comment: and the 'admin' making the choices can't be a logged in user of some sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just started writing one for kicks a few days ago using PHP, MySQL, and Ajax Push Engine (APE).

APE's site is down right now, but check it out when it's up: http://www.ape-project.org/

Comment: So you handle the "draft" in MySQL and handle team on the clock and team on deck and past selections all in MySQL?

Comment: I store draft information in MySQL.  This includes: user information, user assignment to each draft slot, and player selections.

Clock information (countdown, next player on clock, etc.) is handled within APE.  Additionally, whenever a player makes a selection, I have APE send a message to the "channel" to let all the clients update.

Comment: That is pretty much what I am looking at doing. Seems like APE is a good option as it is prebuilt and allows for the communication between server and app that I require. Do you have plans of expanding the project outside of just a fun project?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest an outside process to run the draft itself.  It would place the necessary data in the DB and PHP can be used to act on this data.

The major challenge would be the coordination between that outside process and PHP.

The outside process could be something like a perl script, which could be kicked off with a cron job.

Answer (score 0):

You can have realtime interaction without ajax by using [websocket](http://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js), i wrote a realtime app just like gchat with it, it's pretty realiable apart from flash requeriments.